# not able to access localhost via curl command in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, curl

Im not able to access my localhost via curl command on terminal

```
curl -I 127.0.0.1  gives
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
```

while

```
curl -I example.com is working fine
```

my host file is given below any idea ???

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       jordanism
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: Once again someone who requests help and and yet does not post the answer that they have since discovered for the benefit of others. I'd downvote you if I could_

Comment: @jesusg_forceHarris I agree and downvoted it for you ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I only get this message, if my local webserver is not running. Otherwise it is working fine. My hosts file is identical to yours.

Did you change the configuration of your webserver?

Comment: Hey  I got it :)

Comment: Was it the webserver?